# Firefox Garbled Text

Tags: firefox, encoding, character-encoding, utf-8

In FF 3.5.7 on Vista I am getting garbled text like below on some web pages.

[image: screenshot]

The obvious answer is to go to View > Character Encodings > then select UTF-8.

However, it turns out I am already using UTF-8 encoding and this is still happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Is it just Firefox?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine in both Chrome and IE... weird.

Comment: +1 because I've had this problem before as well. Unfortunately I don't remember how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `about:config` and set [browser.display.auto_quality_min_font_size](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.display.auto_quality_min_font_size) to something improbably-high to turn it off.

I've had this problem with fonts I naively copied-and-pasted from other systems into Windows (eg, really old Mac fonts), and only on Firefox with this setting in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to...

```
Tools > Options > Content > Languages
```

Then make sure everything is correct there.

If that doesn't work try putting it into safe mode then disable all of the plugins to make sure it's not one of them.

[Heres some](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe+Mode) details on how to get Firefox into safe mode

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I surfed to github.com using FF 3.5.7 and didn't get this problem.
(If you have an example of a problematic URL, please post.)

I would suggest uninstalling FF using [revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/), then reinstalling from scratch.
Try then the display before installing any add-ons.
Then install the add-ons in steps, checking the problem every step.